# Printer server set up through router

Tags: applications, printing, router, web-server

I've got an `Epson L220 series` printer and connected it to my `Huawei EG8145V5` router using my printer's usb, I can print wirelessly from my laptop without any problem, but when it's different in android, I tried Epson iprint and other printing apps and all of them doesn't support my printer except from `Let's print droid` as I manage to connect my printer to my android the only problem is it print random characters instead of printing the actual document.
Is there an app the would let me print wirelessly using a usb printer that is connected to a router?

Comment: Have you tried the official [Epson iPrint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=epson.print) respectively the [Epson Print Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.epson.mobilephone.android.epsonprintserviceplugin) app?